# Better way of gathering multiple input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a better way to gather multiple input. At the moment, I am using a slider to represent how many items a user wishes to enter. If a user say selects 3 then I am looking for a way to display a way for them to enter 3 items.

I guess what I need is say if a user selects 3 with the slider, then I need to display 3 input elements with a certain width using the same ID. Say like a bank may ask for your pin. Is this possible. In my example, #boxnumber is the div that needs to be created. Many thanks

```
$(function() {
$("#boxnumber").hide();
$("#slider").live('change', function() {

if($(this).val()>0)
  $("#boxnumber").addClass("ui-input-text").show(1000);
else
if ($(this).val()==0)
  $("#boxnumber").hide(1000);

 });
});
```

+++EDIT+++

```
<div id="boxnumber">
  <label for="boxamount">Enter box numbers *</label>
  <input type="text" name="boxamount" id="boxamount" value="" />
</div>
```

This input is initially hidden.

Comment: Can you maybe show a jsfiddle.net of what your form looks like? (You can select jQuery and jQuery-UI libraries on that site)

Comment: your question is not clear to me

Comment: @brad http://jsfiddle.net/XkfsZ/ for some reason, the spinner keeps going on the code when run. Thanks

Comment: @sazzad at the moment whatever value the user selects on the slider, there is no correlation with the input element that is shown based on the slider. I am looking for a way, that is a user selects 3 from the slider, then they are presented with some kind of input that would make it more in common with the slider.

Comment: Is the slider a selectbox which can select multiple?

Comment: okay im checking here http://jsfiddle.net/XkfsZ/

Comment: @sazzad see here: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b2/#/demos/1.0b2/docs/forms/forms-slider.html

Comment: I don't understand the desired output. Please elaborate.

Comment: @Rikudo ok. at the simplest level I can try to explain. A user moves the slider to say select 3. This value is then used to offer a user a way to input 3 items which will probably be an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this will work:
http://jsfiddle.net/laheab/XkfsZ/4

```
$(function() {
   $("#slider").live('change', function() {
      $('#boxnumber').empty();
      for(var i = 0; i < $(this).val(); i++){
         $('#boxnumber').append(
            '<div>
              <label for="boxamount">Enter box ' + (i+1) +' number:</label>
              <input type="text" name="box-'+i+'-no" id="box-'+i+'-no" />
            </div>'
         );
          }
   });
});
```

Comment: ibrahim works on fiddle but not for me. Dosen't do anything, so guess must be my code. The only think I can think of is my input element i have at the moment. I have updated my question with code. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take HTML like below

```
<div id="slider2box"></div>
```

Then try this jQuery code

```
$(function() {
    $("#slider").live('change', function() {
        $('#slider2box').empty();
        for(var i=0; i<$(this).val().parseInt(); i++){
            $('#slider2box').append('<div class="item" id="item'+i+'"></div>');
        }
    });
});
```

Hope it will work

Now set styles on those **div** to make boxes

Comment: sazzad it dosen't do anything. what is it supposed to do? thanks